# InterruptedException is generated to my asynctask when activity gets an adGenerated

Tags: android, android-asynctask, admob

I have my activity that starts an asyncTask which keeps running  in a loop until the game finishes (4 players game)

The problem is that I introduced Interstitial Ads in the middle of the game (Admob). So when the interstitial start and I close it, I noticed that InterruptedException is sent to my ayncTask causing it to terminate. I suspect that when the ads show, it calls onpause on my current activity (maybe) and a a result this exception is generated. Just a theory. But either way, why is this happening? How can I avoid having this exception /avoid having my asyncTask thread terminate?

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't put an interstitial ad (not sure if they are webview or full activity) in the middle of your game. Use them at the beginning or end of a level/level screen. Also if the loop is long running you might just want to make it a thread rather than a AsyncTask, but still handle it gracefully as the user might have just hit the Home button. [Sorry stream of thought comments to your question - might be helpful]

Comment: Thank you for the advices. Yes it is long. I thought async task is same as thread but just gives more control over gui stuffs. Am I wrong? The game usually run for 8 min

Comment: AsyncTask was intended for basic and relatively short (few seconds) off UI actions in a thread-safe manner. If it works for you fine, but if you need more threads (UI thread, render thread, game loop) then you can read the Android docs on https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html Additional information about posting to UI thread is also in the Android training docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an interstitial displays it appears over the top of your current Activity. This will result in #onPause being called for your current Activity.

At that point you should be pausing any resources you are using (such as an AsyncTask or Thread) and resuming them in #onResume. If your #onPause code is causing your AsyncTask to be interrupted then you will need to deal with that.

As Morrison says above, I wouldn't be showing an interstitial mid game and I wouldn't be using AsyncTask for my game thread. AsyncTask is useful when you want to perform a background operation followed by an operation on the UI thread. I suspect your game thread requires more complexity than that.

Comment: My game thread is just determining which player plays, does some math calculations and then publish to the gui so a card moves. i think aynctask would be enough for that, no?

Comment: But you said "starts an asyncTask which keeps running in a loop until the game finishes". That sounds like a lot more than just determining which player plays, etc.